# Helm --set access list item based on value

Tags: kubernetes-helm

According to [this](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set):

> As of Helm 2.5.0, it is possible to access list items using an array index syntax. For example, --set servers[0].port=80

But is it possible to access a list item based on a value, instead of an index?

Given for example

```
servers:
  - port: 80
    host: example.com
  - port: 443
    host: unknown
```

Is there a way to use it something like this: `--set servers[port==443].host=company.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `helm --set` can't do that; there's no sort of query language there.

For many practical things, `helm --set` has a syntax that's...unique, and it works better to use an overlay value file.

```yaml
# values.company.com.yaml
servers: # replaces the list in the chart's `values.yaml`
  - port: 80
    host: example.com # so this needs to be repeated
  - port: 443
    host: company.com # if you want to just change this
```

```sh
helm install ... -f values.company.com.yaml
```

This limitation also means you may want to restructure your Helm values to be simpler.  A list of maps with `name` keys is pretty common in Kubernetes, but a little hard to manipulate in Helm values.  If you know there will be only these two ports, you could have dedicated values:

```yaml
# values.yaml
httpsHost: unknown
insecureHttpHost: example.com
```

```sh
helm install ... --set httpsHost=company.com
```

Another option is to have two lists, one that's "fixed" and one that has administrator-provided additional values.  The "fixed" one can still be overridden, but if you just need to add values, there's a dedicated place to do that.

```yaml
# values.yaml
servers:
  - { port: 80, host: example.com }
extraServers: []
```

```yaml
# values.company.com.yaml
extraServers:
  - { port: 443, host: company.com }
```

```yaml
# templates/???.yaml
{{- define "server-url" -}}
http://{{ .host }}:{{ .port }}?
{{- end -}}

urls:
{{- range .Values.servers }}
  - {{ include "server-url" . }}
{{- end }}
{{- range .Values.extraServers }}
  - {{ include "server-url" . }}
{{- end }}
```